# Missing classes/words in c# EmguCV version 4.1.0.3420

Tags: image-processing, c#-4.0, emgucv

I was previously using Visual Studio 2010 with EmguCV version 2.2.1 and I now shifted to Visual Studio 2019 with EmguCV version 4.1.0.3420.

This line of code works fine in Visual Studio 2010 with EmguCV version 2.2.1 but doesnt work with Visual Studio 2019 with EmguCV version 4.1.0.3420.

```
//Get the current frame form capture device
currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320,240,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
```

I keep getting the error  **Error CS1061 'Mat' does not contain a definition for 'Resize' and no accessible extension method 'Resize' accepting a first argument of type 'Mat' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Answer (score 0):

That's correct in 4.1, a Mat object does not have a resize method, use CvInvoke.Resize() method instead.

Doug

Comment: I did try it, does not work. CvInvoke showing an error. Although, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
Mat m = new Mat();
grabber.Read(m);
currentFrame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(m.Bitmap);
currentFrame.Resize(320, 240, Inter.Cubic);
```